# Updating string in C# list within for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am learning C# and blazor in an attempt to improve my skills overall.

To do this I am trying to create a simple contact application.
Each contact has the usual name, address, etc as well as a list of social media links.

I have been able to dynamically create new text inputs and have them readable within the contact object but when it comes to updating the list items I get an index out of range error.

This is the rendering of the inputs

```
@if (contact.SocialMedia != null)
{
    @for (int i = 0; i < contact.SocialMedia.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Social Media Link" 
                @bind-value="contact.SocialMedia[i]" />
    }
}
```

These parts handle the creation of new string items and attaching them to the list.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Social Media Link" 
        @bind-value="contactNewSocialLink" 
        @bind-value:after="StashNewSocialLink" />

@code {
    private ContactModel contact = new ContactModel { SocialMedia = new List<string> {"test one", "test two" } };
    private string contactNewSocialLink = "";

    private void StashNewSocialLink()
    {
        if (contact.SocialMedia == null)
        {
            contact.SocialMedia = new List<string>();
        }

        if (contactNewSocialLink.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            contactNewSocialLink = "";
            return;
        }

        contact.SocialMedia.Add(contactNewSocialLink);
        contactNewSocialLink = "";
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Finally this is the error I am receiving after adding some items to the list then trying to edit those items.

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
      System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
         at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)
         at keep_in_touch_system.Pages.Contact.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<BuildRenderTree>b__11(String __value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallbackFactoryBinderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass64_0`1.<CreateBinderCore>b__0(ChangeEventArgs e)
         at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
         at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit 's3-0PyLiGgf2M_pFieMXxD1EffNAP1y2c5GMecLAiD0'.
      System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
         at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)
         at keep_in_touch_system.Pages.Contact.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<BuildRenderTree>b__11(String __value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallbackFactoryBinderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass64_0`1.<CreateBinderCore>b__0(ChangeEventArgs e)
         at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
         at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

Thank you for taking the time to read through this and I hope it is a simple mistake but it has been bugging me for a while.

I have tried to use binding and functions to handle the updating of the list item but haven't been able to solve the problem.

Comment: Use a `foreach` instead of a `for` loop for this

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I've not been able to use a foreach due to the error "Cannot assign to 'SocialMediaLink' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable' 

```
@foreach (string SocialMediaLink in contact.SocialMedia)
{
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Social Media Link"
            @bind-value="@SocialMediaLink" />
}
```

Comment: The code in the question would be fine for `foreach`, as it never assigns to or modifies the iteration variable.

Comment: Capture variable `i` inside loop like `var j = i;` and then use this captured value instead(`j`)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the issue comes in when attempting to update the variable in the input using the bind-value

Comment: @Selvin thanks for that input, I think I have tried that previously but I'll give it another go in case.

Comment: @Selvin I don't believe it but it appears that simply assigning it to a var then using it is fixing the problem...
I could have sworn I had done this previously but this appears to resolve my problem

Answer (score 1):

With much thanks to @Selvin the issue has now been resolved and I feel rather silly.

For reference this is the code that I needed to change as it is working now.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < contact.SocialMedia.Count; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Social Media Link"
            @bind-value="contact.SocialMedia[index]" />
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at this for me all